# Get another Entity while processing an Entity

Tags: odata, olingo

I'am new in Olingo: sorry if my question is strange.

When Olingo service receive request to get entity of EntitySet_1 it calls method of custom entityProcessor (then processor call some storage object and send to it EdmEntitySet and List objects). But this processor method must get entity of EntitySet_2 to end processing. How i can realize getting entity of another entitySet? Or in other words: how can i get entity of another entitySet programatically (is it necessary to create new EdmEntitySet object? etc.) ?

Maybe some ideas, clever words...

Comment: your question is valid, but this is not specific to Olingo(implementation) or Odata (a specification). Tt is more or less about REST service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found only one solution: REST-request to the *same service* for entity of EntitySet_2 while processing entity of EntitySet_1.

Answer (score 0):

Such feature should comes from the design itself. Calling same service from itself is not recommended.

What you should do is utilize the data access methods (ex:- database access method) you already have and get the required EntitySet_2 from it for processing.

For this you will need to create data access requests (ex:- SQL query for EntitySet_2) and map the results to create the EntitySet_2. As I said earlier, the design of your service should be flexible enough for this.